# "Argument is of length 0" when comparing xts objects

Tags: r, xts

This must be very simple, but I can't seem to find the solution. I need to compare the `Close` value for 2 `xts` objects

I have 2 `xts` objects:

```
>low2
low2           daco.Close
2013-07-24     6.63

>low3
low3           daco.Close
2013-07-24     2.63
```

But when I try something like this

```
if(low2$daco.Close < low3$daco.Close) {...}
```

I keep getting the error

```
Error in if (low2$daco.Close < low3$daco.Close) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Even though when I try `print(low2)` or `print(low3)` I get the correct values.

Any tip on how to solve this will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

**Edit**:
Following are the outputs of `low2` and `low3`

```
> dput(low2)
structure(6.63, .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "xxx", updated = structure(1374782893.98805, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(1374451200, tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "daco.Close"))
> dput(low3)
structure(2.63, .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "xxx", updated = structure(1374782893.98805, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(1374624000, tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "daco.Close"))
```

Comment: Those don't look like xts objects.  Please provide the output of `dput(low2)` and `dput(low3)`

Comment: This is the output `structure(6.63, .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", src = "xxx", updated = structure(1374782893.98805, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(1374624000, tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(1L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "daco.Close"))`

Also maybe this helps, `low2 = low2$daco.Close` and when I call low2 I get the output I posted in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Edit that into your question and also provide the output of `dput(low3)`.  Based on what you've provided, all I can say is that it is not reproducible because `if (low2$daco.Close < low2$daco.Close) TRUE` does not give the error you show.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. Indeed if I compare `low2` against itself it works, the same happens with `low3`. Them problem appears when I compare them against each other.

Comment: Thank you. Note that the objects do not have the same Date like you initially showed.  That makes a difference.

Comment: As an aside, it seems a little dangerous to be using syntax like `low2$daco.Close` in an `if` statement like that.  What if there's more than one row in the xts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xts objects are aligned by index before operations are done.  Note that `low2$daco.Close + low3$daco.Close` probably doesn't return what you thought it would either.

This is what you are passing to your `if` statement:

```
> low2$daco.Close < low3$daco.Close     
     [,1]
> str(low2$daco.Close < low3$daco.Close)
An 'xts' object of zero-width
```

You can use `coredata` on one or both of the xts objects.

```
low2$daco.Close < coredata(low3$daco.Close)
#           daco.Close
#2013-07-22      FALSE
```

or you could coerce one or both of them to `numeric` first

```
as.numeric(low2$daco.Close) < as.numeric(low3$daco.Close)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

If they did in fact have the same index it should have just worked.

```
index(low3) <- index(low2)
low2$daco.Close < low3$daco.Close
#           daco.Close
#2013-07-22      FALSE
```